# Prove/disprove: If $n\in \mathbb N$ with $n>2$ not prime, then $2n + 13$ is not prime.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Prove/disprove: If $n\in \mathbb N$ with $n>2$ not prime, then $2n + 13$ is not prime.

From the context in which this question was set, I believe I have to prove/disprove it using contraposition.

I have assumed that $n$ is natural, $n > 2$ and $2n + 13$ is a prime number and I now have to prove/disprove that $n$ is a prime. Hints?

Comment: Look at some small composite $n$ to see that sometimes it is a prime and sometimes not.

Comment: I know that a single counterexample would disprove the statement, but is that the only possible route for this example? I ask only so that I can tackle other similar problems where the calculations are not so simple.

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar To disprove $\forall n \colon\Phi(n)$ is the same as to prove the negation $\exists n\colon \neg\Phi(n)$. And the most straightforward way to prove existence is to exhibit a specific example.

Comment: Then ask rather one of the "other similar problems where the calculations are not so simple".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the counterexample $n=9$.

Answer (score 2):

for $n=8$ we get $$2\cdot 8+13=16+13=29$$ and this is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $n=8$ which is not prime.